# Finding the right marker size for a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to plot a grid where each node in the grid is drawn by a dot, with a certain color code (taken from a vector stored in the node).

[image: my grid]

the grid here varies in size depending on the size of the simulations I am running.  I have yet to figure out the relationship between the canvas size and the marker size.  Now I use the following formula:

```
markersize = (figsize*figsize*dpi*dpi)/(xdim*ydim)
plt.scatter(X, Y, s=markersize/3, marker='s', c=Z, cmap=cm.rainbow)
plt.show()
```

that is I square the sigsize and the dpi (use 15 and 80 respectively), and divide by the dimensionality of the grid.  Finally I divide this by 3 as I found this to work.

But I haven't been able to work out how to analytically get the right marker size.  What I want is a grid where each square uses as much a space as it can but without "infringinig" on the other nodes' space, so that the markers overlap.

As far as I can read the figsize is given in inches.  dpi is - dots per inch, and the markersize is specified in - points.  If the points is the same as dots, you would then have dpi*figsize amount of dots on each axis.  The xdim*ydim is the amount of nodes in my grid.  Dividing the pow(dpi*figsize, 2) / xdim*ydim should then give the amounts of dots per node, and the right size for each marker I thought. But that made the markers too big.  I diveded by 3 and it sort of worked practically for the sizes I usually run, but not for all.  (I am guessing a point and a dot is not the same, but what is the relation?)

How do I work out the correct answer for this?  Ideally I would like a very granular picture where I could zoom in an certain areas to get a finer look at the color nuances.

Comment: Well if you have an isotropic data where fig_size_x=fig_size_y you can do this: 

`marker_size = fig_x*fig_dpi/xdim.
 ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='s',c=areaImg[x,y,z], s=marker_size, zdir='z',
 cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)`.
Then to get the crisp structure you can play with the [interpolation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the marker size precisely and have it scale with the figure, you can use a [patch](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#module-matplotlib.patches) instead of a regular marker. Here's an example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 3, 1, 2, 4]
colors = [10, 215, 30, 100]

cmap = plt.cm.jet
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

for (x, y, c) in zip(x, y, colors):
    ax.add_artist(Circle(xy=(x, y), radius=0.5, color=cmap(c)))      

ax.set_xlim(0, 6)
ax.set_ylim(0, 6)
plt.show()
```

You could also use a rectangle instead of a circle.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion.  but i think iterating over all of these points would be too slow for me.  is there any way to perform an exact calculation of the marker size for a scatter plot?